# Asymptotic expansion of integral (Laguerre)

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider $$L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_{C'} \frac{1}{(1-t)^{\alpha+1} t^{n+1}} e^{-\frac{xt}{1-t}} dt\,\,\,\,(1)$$ where $C'$ is an anticlockwise contour around zero. Now set $\alpha = n$ and I want to find the leading asymptotic behaviour for large $n$.

Attempt: Use the saddle point approximation, so need to put integral in form $$L_n = \int_C g(t) e^{n f(t)} dt$$ I thought about reexpressing the terms dependent on $n$ in the integrand $(1)$ there by exponentials so I could use the method but my choice results in a vanishing second derivative of the function multiplying $n$.

The integral can be rewritten in the following way $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C'}  \exp(n(\underbrace{-\ln(t(1-t)))}_{f(t)}) \underbrace{\exp(-\ln(t(1-t))) \exp(-xt/1-t)}_{g(t)} dt$$

Then $g(t) \approx g(t_o)$ and $f(t) \approx f(t_o) + f''(t_o) (t-t_o)^2/2$. My problem is when I evaluate $f''$ it vanishes.  Should I expand to next power? Many thanks.

Comment: What did you get for $t_0$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Hi, $t_o$ is the saddle point and I got it to be $1/2$. Were you getting the same? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Yes, I got the same, but I got $f''(1/2) = 8$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes I got the same upon doing another recheck, thanks.  Perhaps more importantly, if I can ask, why do we then approximate the original integral over a contour by a linear integral extending from -infinity to infinity.  The infinite bounds make sense if I can understand why we can do a linear integral in the first place.  Is it because we deform the contour to pass through $t_o$ and then subsequently put a tangent at this point that goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Then the dominant contribution is near the saddle point, hence the allowed limit extension?

Comment: That's pretty much correct, yes.  There are a lot of details to verify along the way, though.  It's worth working through them at least once.

Comment: Ok thanks, can I just check though, shouldn't I have obtained a negative for the second derivative? Otherwise in the end I will have a diverging integral?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Pay attention to how your contour will pass through that point, and to the direction of the tangent line.  Then parameterize that line and see if things start making sense.

Comment: ah so this is the stationary phase method? I expand $t - t_o = re^{i \phi}$ and so $(t-t_o)^2 = r^2e^{i2\phi} \Rightarrow \sin 2 \phi = 0$ for stationary phase, giving $\phi = 0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2$,  I choose $\phi = \pi$ since this gives $\text{Re}(f(t)) < 0$.Seem okay?

Comment: sorry, I meant $\phi = \pi/2$.

Comment: Yup, $\phi = \pi/2$, perfect.  (btw I wouldn't say this is related to stationary phase necessarily)

Comment: Thank you, sorry can I ask why?

Comment: The method of stationary phase is about integrals whose contour lies along some path of constant altitude on the surface $\operatorname{Re} f(t)$, more or less.  That doesn't happen in this problem.  This is a very typical saddle point method application.

Comment: Oh right, is that because in this case, we have a saddle point on the real axis?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the saddle point is.  It's called the saddle point method because we deform the contour to pass through the saddle point roughly along the path of steepest descent.

Comment: By contrast, this isn't necessarily a large part of the method of stationary phase, which can proceed by keeping the contour fixed on the path of constant altitide.  However, these terms are kind of fluid; often stationary phase problems can be tackled using the saddle point / steepest descent method, and vice versa.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I am just trying to see how this example in question is not a contour along a constant altitude

Comment: Here's a plot of the surface $\operatorname{Re} f(t)$ and the contour $|t| = 1/2$ in red:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/y4XXG.png  There's nothing "constant altitude" about that contour.

Comment: ah nice, what is the surface of $\text{Re}f(t)$ here? It is proportional to $r^2 \cos 2\phi$?

Comment: By "the surface $\operatorname{Re} f(t)$" I mean the graph of the function $F(x,y) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \operatorname{Re} f(x+iy)$.   This is the surface whose saddle points you want the contour to pass through along their steepest descent lines in these kinds of problems.

Comment: If you have a solution to the problem you should post it as an Answer below :)